# How can I programatically add a user to a team?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a public channel which we would like to link to from an external site. Unfortunately the link which teams gives will not add you to the team. How do I add the user to the team so that the link will kick them into that team's channel?

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no way to add a user except through the team owner's add user interface.  We are working on Office Graph APIs that would support this, but no ETA on that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MS Graph APIs for adding users to the underlying group. It may take up to an hour for it to be reflected in Teams. We are working on enhancing the Graph APIs to eliminate this latency completely.